# Embeded Video on a PHP included page not showing

Tags: php, html, video

The content of my site is loaded through a PHP include, based of off the options a user selects from the menu at the top of the page-- the menu option reloads the index.php page and points it to the content to include.

This works fine for just about anything, except on pages that have embedded video via the HTML `<video>` tag. On those pages, the embedded video still appears to be clickable (i.e., clicking on parts of it will take me to the YouTube page hosting the video) but I can't actually see the video or video player.

Is this something to do with using a PHP include, or is there something else I'm missing? I'd been previously using iframes for my site content, but wanted to get away from that as much as possible.

EDIT: To clarify, this is the behavior I'm seeing when I load the page:
[image]

The video is definitely there; I can save it, and if I right click on it, I get the context menu for the video player. I just can't actually *see* the video. This is the block on the index.php file that actually loads the page content:

```
<div id="frame">
    <?php
        $url = '';
        if (!empty($_GET['menu'])) {
            $url .= $_GET['menu'] . '/';
        }
        if (!empty($_GET['customer'])) {
            $url .= $_GET['customer'] . '/';
        }
        if (!empty($_GET['product'])) {
            $url .= $_GET['product'] . '/index.';
        }
        if (!empty($_GET['pagetype'])) {
            $url .= $_GET['pagetype'];
        }
        if (empty($url)) {
            $url = 'intro.html';
        }
        include $url;
    ?>
</div>
```

All of the `$GET` values are supplied by the link the user selects from the main menu, like so:

```
<li><a class="mainMenuLink" href="index.php?menu=products&customer=customer2&product=product5&pagetype=html">Example</a></li>
```

EDIT 2: Here's the HTML markup generated by the page for the section surrounding the videos:

```
<div id="tabs-5"><!-- start tab 5-->
            <p>Access videos detailing operations and maintenance.</p>
            <div class="accordion">
                <h3>Video 1</h3>
                <div>
                    <video src="./products/coffee/sinf/video/video1.mp4" controls></video>
                </div>
                <h3>Video 2</h3>
                <div>
                    <video src="./products/coffee/sinf/video/video2.mp4" controls></video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end tab 5-->
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, unless you're generating the wrong file paths, which you've said you're not. The fact that the video element is on the page and you're able to save the video implies that everything is fine on the PHP side. The one thing I'd check first is the generated markup of your page.

Comment: I've added the HTML produced by the page to my original post

Answer (score 0):

If you check your console log, and don't see an error for a 404 Not Found, then you are likely not doing anything wrong on the PHP end.

It looks like you are using Chrome, so Inspect Element should let you know if there is any issue loading your include and it not calling the right file path to your video or something.

This could be browser dependent, and it is also recommended (the last I checked) to include multiple file types for HTML5 videos to be cross browser compatible.

This has almost always worked for me -

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay="" controls>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">         
        <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogv">
</video>
```

Adding these lines to your `.htaccess` file will help, too -

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/ogv .ogv
```

VLC has a great open-source player that can convert to the additional file types - http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html

Comment: Looking at Inspect Element, I'm getting a 206 Status on both videos, and the path to them is correct. The file format has never been an issue; I used to load the content page for each product on the site into an iframe, and the videos loaded within the page that was inside the iframe without any problems. So I don't *think* it's a browser or file format issue. I'll try converting them, though, and see if this clears things up in the meantime.

Comment: Try using the absolute URL of the video (for now), not the relative.  See what happens.

Comment: That didn't appear to help; even when using the absolute path to the video, there's still just a big, blank space where the video should be. I can interact with it, save the video, the file is definitely there and the browser sees it. But nothing actually appears on the page itself, and when I try to play the file in-browser, all I see is this: http://s4.postimg.org/dua6mhyt9/no_video2.jpg, while on the old version of the site, I see http://img42.com/swXOm+